# Obtain the GET parameters of URL by RegEx in PHP

Tags: php, regex, url, get

I am on the way of learning regular expressions and I try to find an opportunity to grab the GET parameters from the given URL. For example find the words between **?** and **=** and between **&** and **=**

I have tried something like this

```
$query = $_REQUEST["query"];
preg_match_all('/\B(\?|&).*=\B/', $query, $param_keys);
```

https://regex101.com/r/ZzB4pX/1

But seems it's not working correct. Additionally how can I get the last word which is going right after the last ***=***?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the query parameters with a regex like this:

```
[\?|&](.*?)=([^&]*)
```

Translation: Look for a pattern that starts with either `?` or `&`, followed by the smallest amount of random characters (which we capture in a capturing group), followed by a `=` followed by the largest group of non-`&` characters you can find (also in a capturing group).